# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift5

When I am trying to access array, ends up with this exception but when I add breakpoint on and try to print in the debugger log, array seems to have values and does not appeared to be wrong

```
oldDevices.forEach { (oldDevice) in
                if(self.averageRssis.count > 0){  
                    if(self.averageRssis[oldDevice.bluetoothId] != nil)
                       {
                        self.averageRssis[oldDevice.bluetoothId] = nil
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.bluetoothManager.remove(device: 
                            oldDevice)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1c19ca98c 0x1c0ba39f8 0x1c18e71c8 0x1c19d01d4 0x1c19d1e6c 0x1efc638a8 0x102ef9f44 0x102efa90c 0x102f00f40 0x1efd2f23c 0x102ef965c 0x102f21cf8 0x102eefaec 0x103004c78 0x103007ffc 0x10301a610 0x103015dc8 0x1030167ac 0x1c15ea1b4 0x1c15eccd4)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Are you pressing a button?

Comment: No button click

Comment: What is your "self.averageRssis" ?

Comment: private var averageRssis = [String: [Int32]]()