# NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSTaggedDate member:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000

Tags: swift, core-data, alamofire

I am using AlamoFire 5.0.2 and I'm getting this error randomly and infrequently.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSTaggedDate member:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000
```

```
Thread 14
0  CoreFoundation          ___exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib         _objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation          -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
3  CoreFoundation          ____forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation          ___forwarding_prep_0___
5  libswiftCore.dylib      Swift.Set.insert(__owned A) -> (inserted: Swift.Bool, memberAfterInsert: A)
6  Example App             closure #1 () -> () in AlamoFireSession.perform(DataRequest) -> () (AlamoFireSession.swift:826:33)
7  <compiler-generated>    reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> ()
8  libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_call_block_and_release
9  libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_client_callout
10 libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_lane_serial_drain
11 libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_lane_invoke
12 libdispatch.dylib       __dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib __pthread_wqthread
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib _start_wqthread
```

from `AlamoFireSession.swift`, this *appears* to be what's crashing:

```
self.activeRequests.insert(request)
```

I have multiple `NSManagedObjectContext`s, and am calling `AlamoFireSession.perform(DataRequest)` from inside them and from the main thread.

This means that `AlamoFireSession.perform(DataRequest)` is being called from more than one thread. Could this cause the crash?

Like what if wherever I do this now:

```
AlamoFireSession.default.request(...)
```

I replace it with this:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"all-requests-here")


// and then elsewhere
queue.async {
    AlamoFireSession.default.request(...)
}
```

where the `queue` object is scoped so as to stick around.

I looked around and the most similar thing I found was [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366986/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-nstaggedpointerstring-count-unrecogni), which isn't answered unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If it is `activeRequests`, that issue was fixed in [5.2.0](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/3179).

Comment: thanks, will upgrade to 5.2.0. you're a lifesaver!!

Comment: @spnkr You should update to the latest version, always. Currently it's 5.4.3.